# Sonar runner fails in dryRun mode with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am attempting to perform a dry run analysis of an existing project with Sonar Runner but it keeps failing with a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. I've tried setting sonar.dryRun.excludePlugins=emailnotifications but this does not fix the issue.

My Sonar version is 3.7.4 with Sonar Runner 2.3

Here is my sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=com.example.company:testproject
sonar.projectName=Test Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectDescription=
sonar.language=grvy
sonar.sources=src
sonar.projectBaseDir=.
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.dryRun=true
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Java 1.7.0_25 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Linux 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64 amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: /sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /workspace/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /workspace/.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 3.7.4
09:44:21.156 INFO  - Load batch settings
09:44:21.224 INFO  - User cache: /home/user/.sonar/cache
09:44:21.228 INFO  - Install plugins
09:44:21.234 INFO  - Include plugins: buildbreaker
09:44:21.234 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, jira, pdfreport, views, report, scmactivity
09:44:21.268 INFO  - Dry run
09:44:23.401 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:/tmp/sonar-    batch356768803600806905223669976472392009/dryrun
09:44:24.675 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.528s
Final Memory: 8M/210M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
  at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
  at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
  at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
  at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
  at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
  at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
  at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
  at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/plugins/emailnotifications/api/EmailTemplate
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:386)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
  at org.sonar.plugins.core.CorePlugin.getExtensions(CorePlugin.java:411)
  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.install(ExtensionInstaller.java:52)
  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.installTaskExtensions(TaskContainer.java:56)
  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doBeforeStart(TaskContainer.java:45)
  at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:90)
  at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:156)
  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:144)
  at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
  at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
  at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
  ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.plugins.emailnotifications.api.EmailTemplate
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
  ... 40 more`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin is a core plugin located in \lib\core-plugins, not a plugin that you can manage through the Update Center, as those located in \extensions\plugins. So I don't think you can exclude it from the sonar-project.properties.

Normally, you should have this problem on all projects (under this SonarQube installation). Is that right ?

Did it work before on this project or did you do something meanwhile, like installing a new version ?

I would not be surprised if you had an incorrect version of that jar file. Maybe reinstalling it would work.

Regards.

Comment: We just started attempting to use the Dry Run feature so I'm not sure if it was working previously. Currently it does fail on all projects leading me to believe that there is an issue with the jar like you mention. I'll look into this.

Comment: This was fixed by overwriting the plugins directory with a backed up copy.